# text() not working as expected in processing

Tags: text, processing

I am quite new to processing, but one thing never worked for me. Whenever I use the text() command, the canvas turns grey, even when I have other things like an ellipse, which works flawlessly without the text().

```java
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
}

void draw(){
  ellipse(10,10,10,10);
  textSize(32);
  text("word", 10, 30); 
}
```

This doesn't work me. Neither does just writing:

```java
text("word", 10, 30);
```

Thank you for looking into it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking. You never call the `background()` function, so you'll get the default gray background color. If you want a different color, then call the `background()` function and give it whatever color you want:

```java
void setup(){
  size(400,400);
}

void draw(){
  background(255, 0, 0); //red background
  ellipse(10,10,10,10);
  textSize(32);
  text("word", 10, 30); 
}
```

If this isn't what you're talking about, then please provide a screenshot of exactly what you're talking about, and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right, I should have been more specific to begin with. Actually my problem was, even when I was adding a background, the text didn't show, neither was the ellipse. All I was seeing was a grey background. I just figured out, after waiting 7-8 seconds it works just as expected. Why the delay though, what hinders the program from immediately showing this simple bit of code?
Other more complex programs work without a noticeable delay. The problem only appears when working with text().

Comment: @lkssmnt What operating system are you using? What version of Processing are you using? I don't see any delay when I run the program. I do see a delay if I use a non-default renderer though, but that doesn't seem to be what you're doing here.

Comment: I am using Mac OSX 10.12.1 and Processing 3.2.3. These are the delays I am getting here in millis(): 

at setup: 477
before text(): 682
after text(): 9928

That is not normal, is it?

Comment: @lkssmnt No, that's not normal. Maybe check your video card drivers, update everything?